# get post link by post id from facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a crawler that collect posts from public pages. Most of the time it's work fine, but some times it wan't get the correct Link to the post. For example, this post: https://www.facebook.com/StopBazan/posts/1133146853376672,

`postID: 492380637453300_555826477898431`.

I build the Link by it's PostID: if `PostID: xxxx_yyyy`, then the link is:`"...permalink.php?story_fbid=" + yyyy + "&id=" + xxxx`.
It's not working for this post. 
Is thare is a way to get the Link from the postID by facebook api?

May be it will help someone to answer my question: the problematic post was publish at the 'post to page' part (Visitor Posts) of the page, and it's say that "
‎עוצרים את הרחבת בז"ן‎ shared Elad Flusser's event."

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

If `xxxxxxxxx` is your post id, it's link is `[https://facebook.com/xxxxxxxxx]`

This would work for only `public` posts.[image]

Link:
http://facebook.com/10201864699287377_10205310817078168

Comment: Not realy. https://www.facebook.com/492380637453300_555826477898431, bring you into "Page not Found" page